# References for slow entropy and netropy for Nd and Zd actions

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions, entropy, ergodic-theory

I am studying entropy. Could you give me some references for the the generalizations of entropies, both measure-theoretical and topological, for $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $\mathbb{N}^d$ actions and for the slow-entropies associated with those actions?

Edit

My main interests are the following.
This topic is related to the problem of smooth realization and to the fact that the entropy of an action can be zero even if the entropy of the generators is positive. Could you give some references about those problems?

Comment: Could you perhaps be more precise on what exactly do you want? Note the nothing really changes globally, but locally there is no theory: for example you no longer have a Shannon-McMillan-Breiman theorem.

Comment: I read that the standard definitions of  entropy have problems in those cases: those problems are linked with the fact that the standard definition of entropy is zero in some pretty interesting cases ( smooth realization, or even if the generators of the group acting has positive entropy by themselves). Could you please tell me where I can find a deeper explanation about the fact I'm the sentence I wrote?

Comment: Sure, see my answer.

Comment: As far as I know, there are different ways in which mathematican tried to overcome those problems: Fried entropy and slow entropy are some of those. Are there any other relevant new definitions of entropy that I am missing, obviously for the case Zd or Nd.

Comment: That's another question. I have already replied **to your present question**. But anyways, the answer is yes.

Comment: I modified the question! Thank for you help in understanding what I am interested in

Comment: Sure, as soon as you ask a new question we will have a look a it. This one is already answered.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know I have to do that. In put an "edit" in the main question and I delete the improper part of the question, since I have opened a different question. Now your answer fit  perfectly the question and the edit, as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look for example at the works:

1. A. Katok and J. Thouvenot http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPB_1997__33_3_323_0.pdf.
2. A. Katok, S. Katok and F. Hertz https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0927.pdf

This should be a good starting point.

As I mentioned, there is no local theory coming from ergodic theory. But one can reproduce all that relates to volume growth rates and certainly also the growth rate of the action on the homology.

*PS: This is an answer to the original question, which was later one modified.*